# How to compare (directory) paths in c++?

Tags: c++, path, comparison, cross-platform

I'm looking for a way to check if 2 strings are the same in terms of filesystem path (directory). For example all string from this set are the same in terms of filesystem path: {`/x`,`\x`,`//x`,`/x/`}, but this two - `/x` and `/y` are not, even if `/y` is symbolic link to `/x`. The program I'm going to write should work as for Linux as well for windows, so I'm looking for portable solution.

**EDIT:**

I'm using only header-only libs of boost, so solution with `boost::filesystem` is not ok for me. I know that there is `UrlCompare` in windows API, is there something like in linux?

Comment: +1 good question. Is there an alternative to boost?

Comment: You're using header-only boost for now, but why is that a reason not to add a lib dependency?

Comment: @Tomalak Garet'kal: Because there are a couple of problems with compiling boost in Sun Studio 5.7

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan: Sounds like a good reason. :) Thanks

Comment: The new `std::filesystem::canonical` with C++17 might be able to help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674900/2163727

Answer (score 3):

Any non-Boost solution will involve system dependent code (which is
hidden in Boost if you use Boost).  And you will have to define exactly
what you mean by "matching": should `"./MyFile.xxx"` and `"MyFile.xxx"`
compare equal?  What about `"aaa/.../MyFile.xxx"` and `"MyFile.xxx"`?

The way I would handle this is to define a class with two data members,
an `std::string` with the “prefix” (which would always be
empty in Unix), and an `std::vector<std::string>` with all of the path 
elements.  This class would be doted with the necessary comparison
functions, and would use system dependent code to implement the
constructor; the constructor itself would be in the source file, and the
source file would include a machine dependent header (generally by using
a separate directory for each variant, and choosing the header by means
of `-I` or `/I` to specify which directory to use).  The sort of things
which might go into the header:

```
inline bool
isPathSeparator( char ch )
{
    return ch == '/';
}

std::string
getHeader( std::string const& fullPathName )
{
    return "";
}

bool
charCompare( char lhs, char rhs )
{
    return lhs < rhs;
}

bool
charMatch( char lhs, char rhs )
{
    return lhs == rhs;
}
```

for Unix, with:

```
inline bool
isPathSeparator( char ch )
{
    return ch == '/' || ch == '\\';
}

std::string
getHeader( std::string const& fullPathName )
{
    return fullPathName.size() > 2 && fullPathName[1] == ':'
        ? fullPathName.substr( 0, 2 )
        : std::string();
}

bool
charCompare( char lhs, char rhs )
{
    return tolower( (unsigned char)lhs) < tolower( (unsigned char)rhs );
}

bool
charMatch( char lhs, char rhs )
{
    return tolower( (unsigned char)lhs ) == tolower( (unsigned char)rhs );
}
```

for Windows.

The constructor would then use `getHeader` to initialize the header, and
iterate over `input.begin() + header.size()` and `input.end()`, breaking
the string up into elements.  If you encounter an element of `"."`,
ignore it, and for one of `".."`, use `pop_back()` to remove the top
element of the path, provided the path isn't empty.  Afterwards, it's
just a question of defining the comparators to use `charCompare` and
`charMatch` for `char`, and `std::lexicographical_compare` or
`std::equal` (after verifying that the sizes are equal) with the
comparator for `std::string` (and probably furthermore for your new
class).  Something like:

```
struct FileNameCompare
{
    bool operator()( char lhs, char rhs ) const
    {
        return charCompare( lhs, rhs );
    }
    bool operator()( std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs ) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(
            lhs.begin(), lhs.end(),
            rhs.begin(), rhs.end(),
            *this );
    }
    bool operator()( FileName const& lhs, FileName const& rhs ) const
    {
        return (*this)( lhs.prefix, rhs.prefix )
            || ( !(*this)( rhs.prefix, lhs.prefix )
                && std::lexicographical_compare(
                    lhs.elements.begin(), lhs.elements.end(),
                    rhs.elements.begin(), rhs.elements.end(),
                    *this ) );
    }
};

struct FileNameMatch
{
    bool operator()( char lhs, char rhs ) const
    {
        return charMatch( lhs, rhs );
    }
    bool operator()( std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs.size() == rhs.size()
            && std::equal( lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), *this );
    }
    bool operator()( FileName const& lhs, FileName const& rhs ) const
    {
        return (*this)( lhs.prefix, rhs.prefix )
            && lhs.elements.size() == rhs.elements.size()
            && std::equal( lhs.elements.begin(), lhs.elements.end(),
                           rhs.elements.begin(),
                           *this );
    }
};
```

should do the trick.  (Just remember that the `operator()( char, char )
const` must be in the source file; you can't inline them in the header,
which won't include the system dependent header which defines
`charCompare` and `charMatch`.)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string path1 = "c:\\folder\\";
std::string path2 = "c:\\folder\\folder\\..\\";

boost::filesystem::equivalent(boost::filesystem::path(path1), boost::filesystem::path(path2)
```

The code returns `true`, because the folder are actually the same.

Comment: OP said "so solution with boost::filesystem is not ok for me" in question. Looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/) library - this has path comparison functionality.

EDIT: You could try the [apr](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__filepath.html) - yes it's not C++, however it will be portable.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of portability the Boost filesystem library could be useful ([documentation link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm)). To be more specific: `path.hpp` is most useful, where you could use path comparison.

**EDIT**

[This](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/222551) discussion on gmane.org regards a minimal header-only version of `boost::filesystem`. In summary: This does not exist. So you'll end up in building your own abstraction library and give it cross-platform functionality.

Under Linux there is `dirent.h` which is a POSIX C library. For Windows you'll have to use the Win32 API. However, there is also a so called "Directory-Stream library", which seems to be cross-platform, available [here](http://fara.cs.uni-potsdam.de/~kaufmann/dirstream/index.html) (website is in german).