# How to combine two boost::filesystem::path's?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I need to combine an absolute path A with path B, given that B may be relative as well as absolute, preferably using [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

In other words, I want to have:

- `/usr/home/` + `abc` = `/usr/home/abc`
- `/usr/home/` + `../abc` = `/usr/home/../abc` (or, even better `/usr/abc` - *this is **not** my question*)
- `/usr/home/` + `/abc` = `/abc`

The first two are easy with the `/` operator but I can't get the third one to work.

I tried:

```
std::cout << boost::filesystem::path("/usr/home/") / "/abc";
```

Prints `/usr/home//abc`.

```
std::cout << boost::filesystem::path("/usr/home/") + "/abc";
```

Still prints `/usr/home//abc`.

Of course I can "see" when path B is absolute by looking at it and just use that, but I don't want to hardcode the check for the leading `/` because on Windows it can be different (e.g. `C:\\` or `\\`).

Comment: Check out boost::filesystem::canonical to get paths without the . and .. I believe it also removes the extra /

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "normalize" a pathname using boost::filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746136/how-do-i-normalize-a-pathname-using-boostfilesystem)

Comment: Or even [remove trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941934/parent-path-with-or-without-trailing-slash)

Comment: `/usr/home/ + /abc = /abc` -- That's rather unusual -- normalized, I'd expect this to become `/usr/home/abc`.

Comment: @DanMašek: Not unusual at all. This is basically what any program that accepts a filename does. Given an absolute path, it uses that path directly. And given a relative path, it appends it to the current working directory.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley In that case there has to be some more logic, than simple concatenation and possibly normalization -- like you show in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to make a relative path absolute with respect to some  directory (often the current working directory), there *is* a function to do this:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#absolute

  [image]
- see also [`canonical`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical)

Answer (score 5):

`boost::filesystem::path` has a member function `is_absolute()`. So you can choose your operation (either concatenation or replacement) based on that.

```
path a = "/usr/home/";
path b = "/abc";
path c;

if (b.is_absolute())
    c = b;
else
    c = a / b;
```

There's also `is_relative()`, which does the opposite.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure - there is no function that does this?

Comment: @RustyX: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think there is a function that is better suited (in that it deals with `root_name`s). See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the C++17 `std::filesystem::path`. Its [`operator/`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/append) does exactly what you need.

```cpp
// where "//host" is a root-name
path("//host")  / "foo" // the result is      "//host/foo" (appends with separator)
path("//host/") / "foo" // the result is also "//host/foo" (appends without separator)

// On POSIX,
path("foo") / ""      // the result is "foo/" (appends)
path("foo") / "/bar"; // the result is "/bar" (replaces)

// On Windows,
path("foo") / "C:/bar";  // the result is "C:/bar" (replaces)
path("foo") / "C:";      // the result is "C:"     (replaces)
path("C:") / "";         // the result is "C:"     (appends, without separator)
path("C:foo") / "/bar";  // yields "C:/bar"        (removes relative path, then appends)
path("C:foo") / "C:bar"; // yields "C:foo/bar"     (appends, omitting p's root-name)
```