# Lexical compare std::filesystem::path case insensitive?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

My issue is something like the following: to determine if two paths are identical on the windows platform, paths are compared case insensitive, ei. "C:\test.txt" and "C:\Test.txt" resolves to the same file element. I could solve this easily by using `std::filesystem::equal` for example, but for this particular problem I would like to save a bit on OS roundtripping (running on idle and doing 100+ compares on each loop - I am fearfull it is going to be noticeable)

```
using path = std::filesystem::path;
const bool result =  (path("C:\\test.txt").lexically_normal().make_preferred().native() == path("C:\\Test.txt").lexically_normal().make_preferred().native());
```

When comparing `std::filesystem::path`, even when lexically normalized by calling `lexical_normal` are done in the generic way and thus the case is considered. This makes sense of course, but aside from doing string compare myself I do not see a way to do this with the library without comparing: is it possible to somehow override how paths are compared ?

I also looked into `boost::filesystem`, but as far as i could see does not address the issue either.

Comment: I believe it depends on the OS's filesystem. On Windows it is case insensitive and subsequently `std::filesystem::path` should be the same. On the other hand, on Linux filesystem it is case sensitive.

Comment: Windows filesystem paths are _usually_ case insensitive, but you can enable case sensitivity.  In fact, you can enable case sensitivity _per directory_.  Or you can mount some volumes as case insensitive and some as case sensitive.  So, unfortunately, it will never be as simple as having std::filesystem know which OS it's on.  std::filesystem::equivalent can be useful but only for fully resolvable paths to a file (or directory?) that already exists, which means you're out of luck if you want to test whether a file name has a particular extension in a case-insensitive way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the `path/filesystem` distinction is to make a distinction between the `path` type as a generic mechanism for storing paths that can be manipulated and used with any filesystem, and the `filesystem`-specific operations that may differ based on particular implementations. That two non-equal `path` objects could be considered `filesystem::equivalent` by one filesystem but not by another is just a part of the deal.

There is no mechanism to do perform filesystem-aware `path` "normalization" that isn't a filesystem operation.

Comment: Rather than looking at this in terms of "filesystem awareness", I think it makes more sense to think in terms of application requirements.  How can an application leverage filesystem::path to implement path semantics, while adding the constraint of case-insensitivity?  For example, it may be necessary for a service (such as a git service) to block case-insensitive file path collisions, to support the least common denominator among its clients.

Comment: @JohnDoggett: The filesystem API is not there to allow you to access any filesystem; they exist to allow you to access a specific filesystem: the one provided by your OS. You can try to use the mechanisms with `path` outside of that context of course, but it's probably not going to be great at it.

Comment: It sounds like I misunderstood your opening sentence.  I thought you meant that filesystem and path were intended to be independently good at filesystem access and path semantics, respectively.  Instead it sounds like the path class is only intended to be used in expression of real interactions with a filesystem.  This is unfortunate, because so much of the work in applications is in modeling the *potential* to interact with filesystems, to plan and validate the work before committing it.  That early modeling logic is where the fancy path semantics would have been useful.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you not acknowledge the problem (basicly its impossible to compare FS elements semanticly for some FS types...) ? this answer could be improved a lot if you would suggest at least one solution to the original problem (since the answer is basicly this: "this is not possible").

Comment: @darune: Filesystem-specific comparison has to be part of the *filesystem*, not of the `path`. And if you want to implement that, you're going to have basically extract strings from those paths and compare them via strings, since you don't really have an effective way to access the internals of the `path`.

Comment: @NicolBolas, [ISO/IEC TS 18822](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf):

**4.7 filename**: The following characteristics of
filenames are operating system dependent:

§6 Case awareness and sensitivity during path resolution

**8.4.8 path compare:**

§2 Returns: A value less than 0 if `native()` …

**8.4.6 path native format observers**

§1 The string returned by all native format observers is in the native pathname format.

**4.11 native pathname format**

§1 The operating system dependent pathname format accepted by the host operating system.

Comment: You can use `std::filesystem::canonical` with C++17: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674900/2163727

Comment: The cppreference.com description of `std::filesystem::canonical()` doesn't mention that it does anything to the case of the parameter, so I think it doesn't address this question.